# 555 timer delay circuit + light sensor?

Tags: delay, ldr, light-sensor, 555

I am quite new to electronics and I would like to combine these 2 circuits together so that during complete darkness on the LDR, the LED would turn on instantly and when light falls on the LDR there would be around a 1 or 2 second delay before completely shutting off. I would like this to keep running and not just a one-time thing where once the LED completely shuts off, the LED would not light up again even in complete darkness.

The circuit would be running of a 5V DC power supply and powering an LED array.

I have the 2 circuits below working separately, but have no idea how to combine them together.

I tried connecting the delay circuit to the output of the dark 
sensor (LED) but it did not work.

I would like to achieve the desired effect:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXRto0dwZbM&feature=youtu.be

[image: 555 Timer Delay Circuit]
[image: Dark Detector Circuit]

Answer (score 1):

In the 555 circuit the capacitor controls the wait time, if the capacitor is short-circuited the circuit will wat forever.

In the LDR circuit the transistor acts like a switch but unfortunately it's switching to ground but the capacitor in the 555 circuit is connected to +9V

To resolve this I swapped the parts in the 555 circuit upside down to have the capacitor to ground. Then it was simple to I merge the two circuits.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fORKiJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the dark R1 turns Q1 on the keesp C1 duscharged so 
555 output will be high

when there is light the LDR turns Q1 off and C1 charges , once it gets enough charge the 555 output goes low

I could have instead built the upside-down version of the LDR circuit using a BC557 transitor (or other similar PNP type) instead of the BC547 NPN transistor and merged that with the original 555 circuit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so the above schematic that you sent is using an NPN transistor am I right? Would the circuit run with no problem using a 5V power supply?

Comment: yes, 5V should work too